# Continuous plot while plotting inside a loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot variables dynamically in MATLAB. I have an array (set of states) that needs to be plotted with time. I tried plot(time,theta), where theta is a 1*5 array. With this command, I get an error saying that theta should be a scalar because time is a scalar.  I then tried using for-loop to plot(time,theta(i)). The problem with this is that I get data points at discrete time intervals on my plot. However I need a continuous plot. I wonder how this can be done.

Comment: with `plot(time,theta(1:numel(time)))` I guess. If not, please include a minimal executable example.

Comment: I gather that `time` is a single value, not an array, is that so? It is not clear what you want to do. Maybe plot the last value of theta against current `time`, while keeping the "history" of the plot?

Comment: time is a scalar, theta is an array that stores 5 values at every time instant. So, theta is 1*5 array. At every instant, I want those 5 variables whose value is stored in theta to be plot. At the next time step, I need the 5 variables at (t+1) to be plot and connected (through a line and not discontinuous) with the previous instant data-points.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `hold on` when plotting.

For example:

```
time = 1;
theta = [1:100];
figure

for i=1:100

    plot(time, theta(i),'r.')
    hold on  %--> Keeps the previous data in your plot
    time = time + 1;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I get this straight. Time is updated at every step, and theta are five different variables that also get updated. This should work for you:

```
% Use your own time variable
time = 1:100;

figure;    hold on;
h = cell(5,1);    % Handles of animated lines
colors = 'rgbkm'; % Colors of lines
for t = time
   theta = randn(5,1);
   if isempty(h{1})
       % Initialize plot
       for k = 1 : 5
           h{k} = animatedline(t , theta(k) , 'LineStyle' , '-' , 'Color' , colors(k));
       end
   else
       % Update plot with new data
       for k = 1 : 5
           addpoints(h{k}, t , theta(k));
       end
   end

   % Update plot
   drawnow
end
```

The object `animatedline` was introduced in R2014b. You can still do something similar with a conventional plot and updating the XData and YData properties of the lines at each loop.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, when I tried this, it still gives me an empty plot. I am unable to see anything at all being plot.

Comment: Can you post your code? When I launch this example as-is, it plots theta as a function of time.